# Rainbow Kit not connecting on mobile

Tags: metamask

I have set up Rainbow Kit as described in the docs and everything is working great on local and desktop production/staging environment. However, when testing on mobile with either Brave or Chrome, when you select MetaMask to connect to it opens MetaMask and then does nothing.

There are no errors to report

Struggling to find a solution, there is no info out there about this issue. I have also checked the issues in their Github with no success and seems they(Rainbow.me) does not have a Discord or Telegram

If anyone has had this issue and found a solution or even still having let's chat!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that I explain on this issue :

https://github.com/rainbow-me/rainbowkit/issues/746

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).